# Finding the reciprocal function of the series $\sin z = \sum \cdots$, that is, another series such that the product is $1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Given that

$$\sin z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}$$

verify if there is a multiplicative inverse, that is, a series such that

$$\sin z \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n = 1$$

Is it possible to choose $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$$\sin z = \sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$$
and that an inverse exists?

My idea was to compute the series for $\frac{1}{\sin z}$, is there an easier method? Because it says that I need to verifiy if such series exists. Is there a way to find it without even thinking about $\frac{1}{\sin z}$?

Comment: As $\sin(0)=0$, this is not possible. However, $\frac{\sin z}{z}=1-\frac{z^2}6+…$ has a power series inverse.

Comment: @LutzL what does $\sin 0 =0$ has to do with it?

Comment: You are trying to divide by zero to get the constant term of the inverse series. Resp. you are trying to solve $\sin(0)·b_0=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, but how $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ helps? Shouldn't I find a series for $\sin z $ that has an inverse? Shouldn't it be just a series not centered at $z_0 = 0$?

Comment: Suppose $g(z)$ is a function, defined in a neighborhood of $0$, such that $g(z) \sin z = 1$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$.  Then in particular, $0 = g(0) \sin 0 = 1$, absurd.

Comment: You can find a Laurent series that is inverse to sine at $z=0$. It is $$z^{-1} + \frac16·z + \frac7{360}·z^3 + \frac{31}{15120}·z^5 + \frac{127}{604800}·z^7 + \frac{73}{3421440}·z^9 + \frac{1414477}{653837184000}·z^{11} + \frac{8191}{37362124800}·z^{13} + \frac{16931177}{762187345920000}·z^{15} + \frac{5749691557}{2554547108585472000}·z^{17} + 
    O(z^{19}).$$ As often with the inverse of a difference of exponentials, there will probably be a connection to the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs. I changed the word "inverse" into "reciprocal". The inverse of a sine is of course not $\frac{1}{sinx}$, but $arcsinx$ and that also has a powerseries representation, which is quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert any series that has a positive radius of convergence and non-zero constant term $a_0$.

$$
1=\sum a_k z^k·\sum b_m·z^m =\sum z^n\sum_{0\le k\le n} a_kb_{n-k}
$$
can be recursively solved as $b_0=\frac1{a_0}$ and for $n>0$
$$
b_n=-\frac1{a_0}\sum_{1\le k\le n} a_kb_{n-k}
$$

---

Among other things this means that one can invert the sine series developed around any $z_0$ that is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: So, the answer to "is it possible to find a $z_0$ such that the series has an inverse" is true, because of this?

Comment: Yes, as the constant term is always $a_0=\sin(z_0)$. -- A fun way to write the general coefficient is $a_n=\frac1{n!}\sin(z_0+n\frac\pi2)$.